# Combination of classifiers weka

Tags: machine-learning

I have built three classifiers based on 107 instances,11 features and two classes each stage . Weka used as machine learning tool.

1. First classifier predicts class 0 and class 1-2-3. ( all 107 instances are used for training and testing in cross-validation method)
2. Second classier predicts class 1 and class 2-3.( The instances with class 0 removed for training and testing)
3. Third classifier predicts Class 2 and  Class 3.  ( The instances with class 1 removed for training and testing)

Randoforest is applied to each classifier. Does anybody know how can I combine these three classifiers?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bit werid pack of classifiers, but the most obvious solution would be to build a "meta classifier" on top, which will decide what is the real class. Consider training a classifier on data of form:

Inputs:

- `ourput_of_classifier1(x)` (in unary format)
- `ourput_of_classifier2(x)` (in unary format)
- `ourput_of_classifier3(x)` (in unary format)

Output:

- label of `x`

so you transform your original data into representation consisting predicted labels, and train new classifier on such data.

The simplest possibility would be to train a Naive Bayes to build conditional probabilities in form of `P(final_class=Y | classifier1(x)=y1, classifier2(x)=y2, classifier3(x)=y3)`

Comment: You seem to know what he's talking about, so may I suggest that you take a look at his other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854599/randomforest-classification-weka), which is about the same topic and nobody seems to be seeing (7 views).

Comment: Do you know, how can I combine these cascade classifiers in Weka? The number of instance will change in each classifier because I remove different class label in each part.

Comment: You removed them at the **training** part, it does not mean that they cannot work on it. In fact, it can be valuable for the meta-classifier to know which "other" class it will belond according to those classifiers. So element from class 0 can be translated to for example (0,1,3) (as those 2 additional do not recognize class 0) and you feed meta classifier with ((0,1,3),0), and let it deduce the correct rules for classification.

Comment: Sorry, It is not very clear for me. Can you explain more please.

Comment: Simply speaking: it does not matter how you trained your classifiers. If you train a "meta classifier" it will dedude some rules by itself. For each point (from the WHOLE training) (x,y) compute cl1(x), cl2(x), cl3(x) and create new training pair ( (cl1(x),cl2(x),cl3(x)), y) to use for this new "meta classifier". Even though cl2(x) won't ever equal to 0, its distinction between other classes can still be informative for the classifier to end up with decision "0" (or any other).